# Подсветка ошибки синтаксиса PhpStorm внутри html атрибутов Vue "closing parenthesis expected"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, phpstorm

Борюсь с подчеркиванием синтаксиса внутри PhpStorm, не нравится деструктуризация внутри атрибута v-for, при наведении написано "closing parenthesis expected"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня все корректно подсвечивается при использовании похожего синтаксиса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какую версию IDE вы используете? Похожая ошибка была в версиях 2017.x, она давно исправлена

Comment: 2018.2, по всей видимости нужно обновиться, спасибо за ответ, как обновлюсь проверю :)

Comment: Вы правы! обновился до 2020 и все прекрасно работает, спасибо вам!